# How to find/reference XML element in unknown SOAP tree structure in ESQL

Tags: soap, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I have a Soap message which includes various nested nodes within the Soap body.  I need to find node 'xyz' but it isn't always in the same location.  In the XSLT world I could just use //xyz[1].  Is there equivalent syntax for esql?  Something like OutputRoot.SOAP.Body{unknown syntax}.xyz[1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any equivalent to the xpath '//' syntax in ESQL. If you need it to use it to access a value, you can use a JavaCompute node (see evaluateXpath). Or, you can write a recursive function in ESQL to visit all nodes and test the names. See the CREATE FUNCTION article in Infocenter for an example.

Answer (score 1):

If its always at the same level hierarchically then you can use anonymous references.

I used the following code to get at the Xyz values in the XML.

```
-- Walk all the second level aggregates looking for any that contain the Xyz tag
DECLARE AnonRef REFERENCE TO InputRoot.XMLNSC.*:HasAggregatesWithXyz.*:*[1];
WHILE(LASTMOVE(AnonRef)) DO
    DECLARE XyzRef REFERENCE TO AnonRef.*:Xyz[1];
    IF(LASTMOVE(XyzRef)) THEN
        -- Do something with the value of Xyz
        DECLARE CharVal CHAR FIELDVALUE(XyzRef);
    END IF;

    MOVE AnonRef NEXTSIBLING;
END WHILE;

<HasAggregatesWithXyz>
    <Agg1><NotXyz>NotNot</NotXyz></Agg1>
    <Agg2><Xyz>XyzValue1</Xyz></Agg2>
    <Agg3><NotXyz>NotNot</NotXyz></Agg3>
    <Agg4><Xyz>XyzValue2</Xyz></Agg4>
</HasAggregatesWithXyz>
```

Note: Depending on the XMLNSC parsing options you select, in particular anything to do with preserving whitespace, you may wish to make your reference more specific. To do so you can use types as follows.

```
DECLARE AnonRef REFERENCE TO InputRoot.XMLNSC.*:HasAggregatesWithXyz.(XMLNSC.Folder)*:*[1];
....
MOVE AnonRef NEXTSIBLING REPEAT TYPE;
```

Answer (score 1):

As TJA said, you can simply use anonymous references like this:

```
InputRoot.SOAP.Body.*[1].sender
```